# Facebook "Like" button counter not working

Tags: css, facebook, share, facebook-like

I just added Like/Share buttons on my website. The Share works correctly but the Like button does not. When I select the Like button, it changes color, the counter goes from 0 to 1, but then goes right back to 0.

I've read so much the last two days but have not been able to correct it but one thing I am not sure about is using the URL Linter. Assuming this is where I enter my website URL? If so it gives me:

If I enter my webpage URL it says it was Scraped 7 hrs ago but it also shows two problems:
Admins And App ID Missing
Like Button Tag Missing

How do I correct this??

Answer (score 0):

For sharing posts on facebook it's not necessary to have an app, you can simply share url pages like this:

```
href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.domain.com/test
```

but for liking a post, it is necessary to display information like this example: "John liked this on 'YOUR APP NAME' " which appears on the news feed and stuff, so to have a like button working properly you'll need to set up an app first and then when you create a like button on developers.facebook.com you'll get a code that you will need to insert on your header that looks like this, and it comes already with your app ID inserted in the code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR-APP-ID-HERE&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: This is for a Weebly website which says to use iFrame and not HTML5. Here is the iFrame code.                                                         <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FDavid-Bose-Photography%2F331571697023971&amp;width=250&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:250px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>